# Preserve textarea line breaks via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm looking for a piece of script that will convert a user's textarea line breaks into html on a form submission output so that formatting is preserved in our notification emails.

At the moment I have a couple of fields that require reasonably detailed answers and after submission these come through as one big chunk of text with no line breaks.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Oli

Comment: You should use an editor, like this: http://quilljs.com/

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  Depending on the language you're using to generate the notification emails, you'd replace the new line characters `\n` to HTML line breaks `<br />`.

Comment: The only access I have to the email templates is via a basic editor. In the editor you use keywords to pull through the form answers and you can add html.

Comment: I tried using tinymce and this worked on the front end but just printed the raw html in the email itself... very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get to the bottom of this. Our CMS had a shortcode modifier to convert new lines into line breaks.